# finding proxmox ip address with terraform and Ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform, proxmox

I'm having this code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    proxmox = {
      source = "telmate/proxmox"
      version = "2.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "proxmox" {
  pm_api_url = "https://url/api2/json"

  pm_user         = "user"
  pm_password     = "pass"
  pm_tls_insecure = true
}

resource "proxmox_vm_qemu" "test" {
  count = 1
  name = "test-${count.index + 1}"

  target_node = "prm01"
  clone = "image-here"
  guest_agent_ready_timeout = 60
  os_type = "cloud-init"
  cores = 2
  sockets = 1
  cpu = "host"
  memory = 4048
  scsihw = "virtio-scsi-pci"
  bootdisk = "scsi0"

  disk {
    slot = 0
    size = "32G"
    type = "scsi"
    storage = "local-lvm"
    iothread = 1
  }

  network {
    model = "virtio"
    bridge = "vmbr0"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
    network,
    ]
  }
}

output "proxmox_ip_address_default" {
  description = "Current IP Default"
  value = proxmox_vm_qemu.test.*.default_ipv4_address
}
```

This is created via Ansible playbook. What I'm trying to find is the IP assigned to the machine as I'm running then another playbook to provision that machine. The problem is that I didn't found any solution on how to find the assigned IP address of that machine

Output it is empty!

Any help?

Comment: The output does not work?

Comment: The output it is empty

Comment: Ok, so it says the output will work only if the `agent` is set to `1`. I do not think I can see that in your configuration. Can you add that and retry?

Comment: I need to wait to have qemu agent installed and I'll try again after. Thank you. I'll let you know if this will solve the problem

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!